# How to deal with dead question?

Tags: discussion

What we do with **dead** still-open questions?

By *dead* I mean that the OP had not return to Arduino SE for over a year (and probably will never come back), and therefore the question will be never closed, even if it had acceptable answers posted.

Case: [Where do serialport names come from?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/6527/where-do-serialport-names-come-from).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just answer for the future visitor that did an internet search for the question and upvote any good answers already on the question.

A large part of SE philosophy is to help the future visitor as much as the current asker.

Comment: If the OP never comes back, the question will remain open forever, even with an answer. How do we close it if it was already answered?

Comment: It doesn't need to be "closed", when there is a upvoted answer the system will consider it answered in all but name.

Comment: Unfortunately, many of these are weak questions where only poor answers not deserving upvotes are likely to be posted.  Often the question itself must be closed as it is either unclear or not a fit for the Stack Exchange model.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you necessarily mean *closed* but rather *has an accepted answer*, and as such, is thus removed from the list of unanswered questions. I noticed such a question yesterday: [HC-12 with Arduino Mega](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/46062/hc-12-with-arduino-mega).

It is a reasonably presented question, with code and a schematic, and it seems as if the user had found a solution. However, an answer was never posted, and even though a suitable answer *could* be extracted from the comments (see [What if a comment solve the question?](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2400/what-if-a-comment-solve-the-question)), the OP may never return to mark it as accepted and therefore remove the question from the unanswered list of questions.

Another example, but where there is already an answer, is [How to get the server response when I post to a web api](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39705/how-to-get-the-server-response-when-i-post-to-a-web-api)

There was a meta question (to which Nick gave an answer to) about having moderators marking an answer which is an obvious solution to a question, as the accepted answer, see [Questions with good answers but none accepted](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/questions-with-good-answers-but-none-accepted).